# How to find a given value appears in what tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables.

Given a discount value, I want to find if that discount value appears in what tables and their corresponding `userids`.

E.g: lets say `12% discount`. I want to check if `12% exists` in what tables (e.g., table 2, table 3) and what are their `userid`

Note: discount value appears only one time in a given table (unique discounts)

Can someone please help me :)

Tables

```
table1(userid,discount)  
table2(userid,discount)    
table3(userid,discount)    
table4(userid,discount)    
table5(userid,discount)
```

Comment: 1. Learn how to design a database - combine your tables into a single table. 2. If for some undisclosed reasons you need to have 5 separate tables with the same structure, then use union to combine the queries.

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query :-

```
Select * from 
(
select  userid,discount  from table1
union
select  userid,discount  from table2
union
select  userid,discount  from table3
union
select  userid,discount  from table4
union
select  userid,discount  from table5
) 
dis where dis.discount = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from (select  userid,discount  from table1
union All
select  userid,discount  from table2
union All
select  userid,discount  from table3
union All
select  userid,discount  from table4
union All
select  userid,discount  from table5
 ) a where discount = 12
```

Hope thisone will help to get answer.